# React for loop returns Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-dom

I am for looping an HTMLCollection with the goal of updating the style of every `p` tag. My problem is that I get `Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` and I don't know why.

```
var getp = document.getElementsByClassName(currentUser[0]?.username)
   for (let i of getp) {
       console.log(i?.style);
       i?.style.background = 'red'
}
```

Comment: just remove chaining operator and use a simple dot

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just remove left-hend side `?`

from

```
i?.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

to

```
    i.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the for loop with an Array or just a regular for loop like this

```
var getp = document.getElementsByClassName(currentUser[0]?.username);
for (let i = 0; i < getp.length; i++) {
  console.log(getp[i].style);
  getp[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

tested and working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

We can simple use `for` loop to resolve this issue

```
var getp = document.getElementsByClassName(currentUser[0]?.username);
for (let i = 0; i < getp.length; i++) {
    var pElement = getp[i];
    console.log(pElement.style);
    pElement.style.background = 'red';
}
```

It will work perfectly.